# I want to create(or atleast adopt) a new "customised" scheduler in hadoop. I saw a bunch of Scheduling Algorithms online that are stated as below

Tags: hadoop-yarn, scheduler, hadoop2

I want to create(or atleast adopt) a new "customised" scheduler in hadoop. I saw a bunch of Scheduling Algorithms online that are stated as below.
[Hadoop Scheduling Algorithms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmblQ.png)

I know we can extend classes from resourcemanager/scheduler/ class in yarn-server and write-up our own scheduling algorithms. But can someone give me an example of one customized algorithm they wrote, or atleast give me a path where I could find them(jar files).

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at the [code for fairscheduler](https://github.com/naver/hadoop/blob/master/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/fair/FairScheduler.java)? And compare it with [Capacity Scheduler](https://github.com/naver/hadoop/blob/master/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/resourcemanager/scheduler/capacity/CapacityScheduler.java)?  These are great examples of how to create your own custom algorithm.

Comment: That's actually quite clever and interesting. Thanks for the advice!